# Filtering words from a list that matches my char in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I just started to learn scheme.
I need to create a predicate function that will filter a list(maybe empty) and only output if they match with a char:

```
(filter-word '((#\g #\a #\m #\e)
               (#\d #\o #\l #\l)
               (#\d #\i #\c #\e))
              #\a)
```

output:

```
((#\g #\a #\m #\e))
```

I'm trying to use filter and member, but I don't know how to structure this function, and I don't know if is possible to use filter lambda and member altogether.
Is Map a better option for this case?

```
(define (filter-word words ch)
  (cond
    [(null? words) words]
    [(filter
     (λ (words)(member? ch (words)) words))]))
```

I know is incomplete but in this case, the output is #<procedure:...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` directly, there's no need for an extra case. This should work:

```
(define (filter-word words ch)
  (filter (lambda (word) (member ch word))
          words))
```

For example:

```
(filter-word '((#\b #\u #\s)
               (#\b #\a #\r)
               (#\c #\a #\r))
             '#\b)
=> '((#\b #\u #\s) (#\b #\a #\r))

(filter-word '((#\b #\u #\s)
               (#\b #\a #\r)
               (#\c #\a #\r))
             '#\c)
=> '((#\c #\a #\r))
```